# Sencha Touch radiofield value

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

I am trying to get the values of form elements in sencha touch.  I am using

fields= form.getFields();
var name = fields["name"].getValue();

This is working for most of my fields, but not for my radio button field.
I am using two radio fields with the same name of 'gender' that have values of male or female.  I tried the above code for this field, but I get an error that the radiofield has no method getValue().  However, in the sencha touch documentation under Ext.form.radio it says that radio does have the method.  What is the correct way to get the value of a radio group?

Comment: Have you tried passing a record into your form and then calling this.updateRecord(this.record). With this method you'll be able to utilize the loading and saving power of a model while also being able to extract form values easily.
http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/docs/?class=Ext.form.FormPanel

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/docs/source/FormPanel.html#method-Ext.form.FormPanel-updateRecord

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var fields = form.getValues();
console.log(fields['name']);
```